# The toggle in the script isn't working for me

Tags: javascript, html

I'm using this code that I found online, but it's not working completely the way I want it to.

Basically I am wanting check boxes to hide divs based on the users selection.
I am building an allergens advice page for a restaurant. When a guest selects the allergens they have I want it to hide the dishes that they cannot have.

The above code works perfectly if the guest has one allergen. It hides the div. If they select more than one then the box will reappear.

```js
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function() { 
    var inputValue = $(this).attr("value"); 
    $("." + inputValue).toggle(); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="selectt Eggs Gluten"> 
    <strong>Dough Balls</strong><br/> 
    Cheese dough balls served with chipotle butter.
</div>
<ul>  
    <li> 
        <input type="checkbox" id="checkboxThree" value="Eggs">
        <label for="checkboxThree"> Eggs</label>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I'm guessing it's doing it because the code is toggling, but I don't know of any other code to prevent that.
Your help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you please create a small [reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for debugging purpose?

Comment: Sure: http://www.pollardfraser.co.uk/test.html - Use Gluten and Milk. Thank you.

Comment: I'm sorry Palash, I have no idea what a reproducible example is! ha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just copied further code from the link

What is happening here is just checkbox from `ks-cboxtags` class will be affected so any other checkbox will not have this functionality.

when you click on this it will displays div and if its selected div will be hide.

check below snippet for more details.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".test").click("test"); //ignore this
    
    $(".ks-cboxtags input").click(function() {
        $("."+$(this).val()).show();
        $(".ks-cboxtags input:checked").each(function() {
            $("."+$(this).val()).hide();
        });
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<main class="inline-block-center">
  <div class="selectt Gluten" style="display: block;">
    <strong style="font-size: 18px;">MEXICAN POPPADOMS</strong><br> Crispy blue corn tortillas with roasted tomato salsa, habanero &amp; pepper salsa, green tomatillo &amp; jalapeÃ±o salsa.</div>

  <div class="selectt Eggs Gluten" style="display: block;">
    <strong>PAO DE QUEIJO</strong><br> Traditional Brazilian cheese dough balls served with chipotle butter.</div>

  <div class="selectt Gluten" style="display: block;">
    <strong>PERUVIAN BOTIJA OLIVES</strong><br> In a herby marinade.</div>

  <div class="selectt Milk Gluten" style="display: block;">
    <strong>TEQUENOS</strong> <br> A popular Venezuelan street food; cheese filled fried bread sticks served with chipotle butter.</div>
</main>

<ul class="ks-cboxtags">

  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkboxOne" value="Gluten">
    <label for="checkboxOne"> Gulten</label>
  </li>

  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkboxTwo" value="Crustaceans">
    <label for="checkboxTwo"> Crustaceans</label>
  </li>

  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkboxThree" value="Eggs">
    <label for="checkboxThree"> Eggs</label>
  </li>

  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkboxFour" value="Fish">
    <label for="checkboxFour"> Fish</label>
  </li>

  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkboxFive" value="Peanuts">
    <label for="checkboxFive"> Peanuts</label>
  </li>

  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkboxSix" value="Soy Beans">
    <label for="checkboxSix"> Soy Beans</label>
  </li>

  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkboxSeven" value="Milk">
    <label for="checkboxSeven"> Milk</label>
  </li>

  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkboxEight" value="Tree Nuts">
    <label for="checkboxEight"> Tree Nuts</label>
  </li>

  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkboxNine" value="Celery">
    <label for="checkboxNine"> Celery</label>
  </li>

  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkboxTen" value="Mustard">
    <label for="checkboxTen"> Mustard</label>
  </li>

  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkboxEleven" value="Seasame">
    <label for="checkboxEleven"> Seasame</label>
  </li>

  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkboxTweleve" value="Sulphur">
    <label for="checkboxTweleve"> Sulphur</label>
  </li>

  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkboxThirteen" value="Lupin">
    <label for="checkboxThirteen"> Lupin</label>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Absolutely perfect. Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 1):

Your code throws unexpected end of input, you are missing closing parentheses for `$(document).ready()`:

```js
$(document).ready(function() { 
                $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function() { 
                    var inputValue = $(this).attr("value"); 
                    $("." + inputValue).toggle(); 
                });
                
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="selectt Eggs Gluten"> 
        <strong>Dough Balls</strong><br/> 
        Cheese dough balls served with chipotle butter.</div>
            <li> 
                <input type="checkbox" id="checkboxThree" value="Eggs">
                <label for="checkboxThree"> Eggs</label>
            </li>
```

In the case of multiple checkboxes that refer to the same product that should stay hidden:

```js
   $(document).ready(function() { 
                    $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function() {                          
                            var inputValue = $(this).val(); 
                           
                            if($(this).is(':checked')){
                               $("." + inputValue).hide();                                  
                            }else{
                               $("." + inputValue).show();
                            }
                    });
                    
      });
```

```html
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div class="selectt Eggs Gluten"> 
            <strong>Dough Balls</strong><br/> 
            Cheese dough balls served with chipotle butter.</div>
                <li> 
                    <input type="checkbox" id="checkboxThree" value="Eggs">
                    <label for="checkboxThree"> Eggs</label>
                </li>
                <li> 
                    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox4" value="Gluten">
                    <label for="checkbox4"> Gluten</label>
                </li>
```

Comment: That is in the script I just didn't copy it on here. My apologies. Any idea how to stop it reappearing when a second checkbox is selected?

Comment: You can just use same selector on all to hide all except the one with special selector from value: `$('.selectt').hide()`

Comment: I'm sorry niklaz, you are talking to an extremely inexperienced person here! ha. Please could you elaborate?

Comment: @NathanPollard-Fraser, no probs. What do you want to achieve with the code? Do you want to have all the descriptions hidden for all checked items?

Comment: Putting it very simply, as I'm sure you're pretty busy and I don't want to waste your time. A div could have more than one class to it (In my case, it could have gluten and eggs) When I click gluten it hides the div, but when I click eggs, it makes it reappear. What I need is that if gluten is selected it hides the div and then if eggs is selected after, it still hides the div. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: @NathanPollard-Fraser, I have edited my answer, please check the second example that should fit your needs

Comment: @niklaz You approach is not enough. If you click Eggs, the Dough Balls disappear (correct), if you click Gluten, the Dough Balls remain hidden (correct). But if I click Gluten [or Eggs] again, the Dough Balls reappear (wrong), but it should remain hidden

Answer (score 0):

I've rewritten the code without jQuery, as it doesn't seem to need it...

Here is the pen: https://codepen.io/paulmartin91/pen/ExjgQBJ?editors=1011

JS

```
    //object containing each allergen. Add them to this object when adding them to the list - always set to false as default
let choices = {
    Eggs: false,
    Gluten: false
  }

let clickedBox  = (input) => {
  //mark the selected allergen as checked
  choices[input.value] = input.checked 
  //returns an array of classes for each element with the selected allergen
  let selected = document.getElementsByClassName(input.value)
  //iterates though array of elements with selected allergen
  for (let i = 0; i < selected.length; i++) {
    //creates an array of classes for each element
    var classList = selected[i].className.split(' ')
    var counter = 0
    classList.forEach(x=>{
      //if the element contains a class that is checked, hide it
      if (choices[x]) {selected[i].style.display = 'none'} else{
        //count the number of classes that aren't checked
        counter++
        //if the element has no classes that are checked, show it
        if (counter == classList.length) {selected[i].style.display = 'block'}
      };
    })
  }
  };
```

HTML

```
<div class=" Eggs Gluten"> 
        <strong>Eggs Gluten</strong>
</div>
<div class="Eggs "> 
        <strong>Eggs</strong>
</div>
<div class="Gluten "> 
        <strong>Gluten</strong>
</div>

<li> 
  <input 
         onclick = 'clickedBox(this)' 
         type="checkbox"
         id="checkboxOne" 
         value="Eggs">
  <label for="checkboxOne"> Eggs</label>
  <input 
         onclick = 'clickedBox(this)' 
         type="checkbox"
         id="checkboxTwo" 
         value="Gluten">
  <label for="checkboxTwo"> Gluten</label>

</li>
```

It now iterates through all the elements that match the class and hide/show them based on the condition of the checked box.

Hope this helps!

Edit: fixed code, should work now!

Comment: Hi Paul. Thank you so much. That works really well, but I'd need it the other way. So at the moment that code is showing the divs when the tick box is selected. I'd like it to hide the boxes when the allergy is selected. Does that make sense?

Comment: My mistake. No it's not. That's absolutely perfect. Thank you very much!

Comment: Glad I could help!

Comment: Oh no, it doesn't work actually. Now if I select gluten and eggs, it stays hidden, which is perfect, but if I unselect eggs, it presents itself again even though it has gluten in it, so shouldn't show. Any ideas buddy?

Comment: Hi Nathan, looks like someone else has solved your issue, but for what it is worth, I fixed my code so it should work now. Glad you got it sorted!

Comment: Thank you Paul for all your help!